# Get latest tweets of specific user

Tags: javascript, twitter, tweets

I need to get the latest tweets of specific user using javascript. I've found some script for that. Here is it:

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            loadLatestTweet();
        });
        function loadLatestTweet(){
            var numTweets = 1;
            var _url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/CypressNorth.json?callback=?&count='+numTweets+'&include_rts=1';
            $.getJSON(_url,function(data){
                for(var i = 0; i< data.length; i++){
                    var tweet = data[i].text;
                    var created = parseDate(data[i].created_at);
                    var createdDate = created.getDate()+'-'+(created.getMonth()+1)+'-'+created.getFullYear()+' at '+created.getHours()+':'+created.getMinutes();
                    tweet = tweet.parseURL().parseUsername().parseHashtag();
                    tweet += '<div class="tweeter-info"><div class="uppercase bold"><a href="https://twitter.com/#!/CypressNorth" target="_blank" class="black">@CypressNorth</a></div><div class="right"><a href="https://twitter.com/#!/CypressNorth/status/'+data[i].id_str+'">'+createdDate+'</a></div></div>'
                    $("body").append('<p>'+tweet+'</p>');
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

but i get an error, that says `Status Code:401 Unauthorized`. I've changed the version code to 1.1, but the same error. So, I want to know, how can I pass the application id or application key to this url. And more, is there any javascript lib which works with the newest twitter api. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer to this is version 1.0 is no longer active and version 1.1 requires OAuth for almost every api endpoint url.